# Why is my protected HTTP triggered Azure Function App sometimes returning a 401 status code?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

**Context**

I have several micro-services spread across multiple HTTP triggered `Function App`s running in a Consumption Plan on Linux and, up until recently, all the Function App instances were using `AuthenticalLevel` set to `Anonymous`.

Now, I have switched the `AuthenticalLevel` to `Function` and created Function App keys. Of course, all the clients use the `x-functions-key` header with the correct key.

It works *most* of the time.

**Problem**

However, if I call a function in one of the Function Apps that has not been called in a while, I get an HTTP status code of `401 - Unauthorized` and the functions in my Function Apps are not triggered.

Now, the weird part is that if I restart the Function App, it works again.

**Investigation**

I had a hard time finding any clues about what was going on because every time I started logging, it worked again. I left one of my application insights log window opened for a while and I have been able to get the following trace in one of the Function App that started to fail:

```
[Information]   Executing StatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 401
```

I do not know what the error means and upon search, I have found the error [mentioned on Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/28288#issuecomment-478493545) in the following comment:

> If you get 401 Unauthorized, find the file function.json, change
> authLevel to anonymous if it is set to function(default value in
> template). We can't access http trigger in a local container with
> authlevel other than anonymous. Because we don't have function keys
> yet, which are available after we create a Function app using the
> container.

I am not using container (at least not explicitly) so I am worrying that the issue I am facing is out my area of expertise.

**Question**

Why is the `401` code returned knowing the key used in the header is correct? Is it possible to protect my Function Apps running in a Consumption Plan on Linux using a Function Key?

**Logs**

Here are more logs starting at the time the request is received by the function host:

```
[Verbose]   Request successfully matched the route with name 'v1-get-account' and template 'api/v1/accounts'
[Information]   Request [37760fe9-e2cb-4555-b053-09fc7e294d41] HEAD https://<function_app_dedicated_storage>.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-secrets/<function_app_name>/host.json
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
Accept:application/xml
x-ms-client-request-id:37760fe9-e2cb-4555-b053-09fc7e294d41
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.13.0,(.NET 6.0.6; Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022)
x-ms-date:Sun, 25 Dec 2022 16:16:36 GMT
Authorization:REDACTED
client assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs
[Information]   Response [37760fe9-e2cb-4555-b053-09fc7e294d41] 200 OK (00.0s)
Accept-Ranges:bytes
ETag:"0x8DACA94982533A3"
Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id:e0db0aa4-801e-00a6-2d7c-18269c000000
x-ms-client-request-id:37760fe9-e2cb-4555-b053-09fc7e294d41
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
x-ms-creation-time:Fri, 12 Aug 2022 23:37:07 GMT
x-ms-lease-status:unlocked
x-ms-lease-state:available
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-server-encrypted:true
x-ms-access-tier:Hot
x-ms-access-tier-inferred:true
Date:Sun, 25 Dec 2022 16:16:35 GMT
Content-Length:1109
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Content-MD5:LuFKWHapYzSmnjxmromAuw==
Last-Modified:Sun, 20 Nov 2022 01:14:38 GMT
[Information]   Request [9fe0455e-4e3e-497e-8b1f-a13128d8920c] GET https://<function_app_dedicated_storage>.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-secrets/<function_app_name>/host.json
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
Accept:application/xml
x-ms-client-request-id:9fe0455e-4e3e-497e-8b1f-a13128d8920c
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.13.0,(.NET 6.0.6; Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022)
x-ms-date:Sun, 25 Dec 2022 16:16:36 GMT
Authorization:REDACTED
client assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs
[Information]   Response [9fe0455e-4e3e-497e-8b1f-a13128d8920c] 200 OK (00.0s)
Accept-Ranges:bytes
ETag:"0x8DACA94982533A3"
Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id:e0db0aa9-801e-00a6-317c-18269c000000
x-ms-client-request-id:9fe0455e-4e3e-497e-8b1f-a13128d8920c
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
x-ms-creation-time:Fri, 12 Aug 2022 23:37:07 GMT
x-ms-lease-status:unlocked
x-ms-lease-state:available
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-server-encrypted:true
Date:Sun, 25 Dec 2022 16:16:35 GMT
Content-Length:1109
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Content-MD5:LuFKWHapYzSmnjxmromAuw==
Last-Modified:Sun, 20 Nov 2022 01:14:38 GMT
[Information]   Request [532132a5-3186-4397-b913-08a0d8a8bb55] HEAD https://<function_app_dedicated_storage>.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-secrets/<function_app_name>/v1-get-account.json
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
Accept:application/xml
x-ms-client-request-id:532132a5-3186-4397-b913-08a0d8a8bb55
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.13.0,(.NET 6.0.6; Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022)
x-ms-date:Sun, 25 Dec 2022 16:16:36 GMT
Authorization:REDACTED
client assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs
[Information]   Response [532132a5-3186-4397-b913-08a0d8a8bb55] 200 OK (00.0s)
Accept-Ranges:bytes
ETag:"0x8DA7CBB927ADEE5"
Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id:e0db0aac-801e-00a6-347c-18269c000000
x-ms-client-request-id:532132a5-3186-4397-b913-08a0d8a8bb55
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
x-ms-creation-time:Fri, 12 Aug 2022 23:37:08 GMT
x-ms-lease-status:unlocked
x-ms-lease-state:available
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-server-encrypted:true
x-ms-access-tier:Hot
x-ms-access-tier-inferred:true
Date:Sun, 25 Dec 2022 16:16:35 GMT
Content-Length:519
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Last-Modified:Fri, 12 Aug 2022 23:37:08 GMT
[Information]   Request [208dd98f-c802-4ea2-85eb-525716290cc4] GET https://<function_app_dedicated_storage>.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-secrets/<function_app_name>/v1-get-account.json
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
Accept:application/xml
x-ms-client-request-id:208dd98f-c802-4ea2-85eb-525716290cc4
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.13.0,(.NET 6.0.6; Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022)
x-ms-date:Sun, 25 Dec 2022 16:16:36 GMT
Authorization:REDACTED
client assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs
[Information]   Response [208dd98f-c802-4ea2-85eb-525716290cc4] 200 OK (00.0s)
Accept-Ranges:bytes
ETag:"0x8DA7CBB927ADEE5"
Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id:e0db0ab0-801e-00a6-377c-18269c000000
x-ms-client-request-id:208dd98f-c802-4ea2-85eb-525716290cc4
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
x-ms-creation-time:Fri, 12 Aug 2022 23:37:08 GMT
x-ms-lease-status:unlocked
x-ms-lease-state:available
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-server-encrypted:true
Date:Sun, 25 Dec 2022 16:16:35 GMT
Content-Length:519
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Last-Modified:Fri, 12 Aug 2022 23:37:08 GMT
[Information]   Executing StatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 401
```

Comment: Can you post all the logs coming from the request that is returning status 401?

Comment: @funatparties I have added all the logs related to the failing request.

Comment: how are you deploying your app? Via portal or using cli/git? This answer may explain the behaviour you are getting https://stackoverflow.com/a/72384971. When the app isn't getting hits it gets paused, and then when you request it, it gets re-started, and it may be mixing some settings.

Comment: I have setup a CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps. It uses the staging slot for warm-up / smoke test and then swaps between the staging slot and the production slot.

Comment: Check if maybe you are applying different settings when deploying using pipeline vs when you are restarting them manually. Other than that, there could be a lot of reasons why is it happening and probably need live investigation of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to make it work.

I switched to a `keyvault` as the mean to store the `Function App` keys and the problem disappeared. The settings of the `Function App` looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
    ...
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"              : "dotnet-isolated",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION"           : "~4",
    
    "AzureWebJobsStorage"                   : "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storageaccount_name>;AccountKey=<storageaccount_key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType"        : "keyvault",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageKeyVaultUri" : "https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net"
    
    ...
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7075,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```